# How to filter records with multiple cases for single column using Azure data flows

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to filter records where column1 not equals to (6,8,9,10) using Azure dataflows and Filter transformation.

Comment: Hi @user13949321, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: It was correct joseph.Thank you for your support.

Comment: Hi @user13949321 If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use `!(equals(column1,6) || equals(column1,8) || equals(column1,9) || equals(column1,10))` expression in the Filter, it will filter records where column1 not equals to (6,8,9,10).